# How to compare Debian package versions?

Tags: python, debian, apt

I looked at `python-apt` and `python-debian`, and they don't seem to have functionality to compare package versions. Do I have to write my own, or is there something I can use?

Ideally, it would look something like:

```
>>> v1 = apt.version("1:1.3.10-0.3")
>>> v2 = apt.version("1.3.4-1")
>>> v1 > v2
True
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You could use [apt_pkg.version_compare](https://apt-team.pages.debian.net/python-apt/library/apt_pkg.html#apt_pkg.version_compare):

```
import apt_pkg
apt_pkg.init_system()

a = '1:1.3.10-0.3'
b = '1.3.4-1'
vc = apt_pkg.version_compare(a,b)
if vc > 0:
    print('version a > version b')
elif vc == 0:
    print('version a == version b')
elif vc < 0:
    print('version a < version b')
```

yields

```
version a > version b
```

---

Thanks to Tshepang for noting in the comments that
for newer versions: `apt.VersionCompare` is now [`apt_pkg.version_compare`](https://apt-team.pages.debian.net/python-apt/library/apt_pkg.html#apt_pkg.version_compare).

Comment: I guess your packager installed it in a different place. I found it [here](http://apt.alioth.debian.org/python-apt-doc/library/apt_pkg.html#apt_pkg.version_compare). And that's about the same place I fin mine also. I also think you have an old version of python-apt because they are moving away from CamelCase, and I guess that's why it isn't documented.

Comment: @Tshepang: Indeed, my python-apt is pretty old. Thanks for the update

Comment: Actually, your code works fine. The developers were prudent enough to keep it as some sort of alias for newer method names.

Comment: Also, `apt.version_compare` doesn't work. Use `apt_pkg.version_compare` instead.

Comment: I end up with `ValueError: _system not initialized` if I use `apt_pkg.version_compare()`.

Comment: @NathanOsman: My mistake. The code above was missing a call to `apt_pkg.init_system()`. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/172311/3330.

Comment: links are dead. try https://apt-team.pages.debian.net/python-apt/library/apt_pkg.html#apt_pkg.version_compare

Answer (score 76):

Perhaps because the title doesn't mention Python (though the tags do), Google brought me here when asking the same question but hoping for a bash answer.  That seems to be:

```bash
$ dpkg --compare-versions 11a lt 100a && echo true
true
$ dpkg --compare-versions 11a gt 100a && echo true
$
```

To install a version of rubygems that's at least as new as the version from lenny-backports in a way that gives no errors on lenny and squeeze installations:

```bash
sudo apt-get install rubygems &&
VERSION=`dpkg-query --show --showformat '${Version}' rubygems` &&
dpkg --compare-versions $VERSION lt 1.3.4-1~bpo50+1 &&
sudo apt-get install -t lenny-backports rubygems
```

Perhaps I should have asked how to do that in a separate question, in the hope of getting a less clunky answer.

Comment: For info, for Python in 2021, this is the best solution. There are a lot of Debian versions format not supported by the lib mentioned in other answsers. Making a Python function that call the bash command in this answers works like a charm. `return subprocess.call(['dpkg', '--compare-versions', '11a', 'gt', '100a']) == 0`

Comment: @PierreF "best" is subjective in this context. This code will only run on a debian fork version of linux.  There's various contexts, including CI pipelines where you may want to compare Debian versions and not have `dpkg` available.

Answer (score 8):

`python-debian` can do this too. It's used in an almost identical way to `python-apt`:

```
from debian import debian_support 

a = '1:1.3.10-0.3'
b = '1.3.4-1'
vc = debian_support.version_compare(a,b)
if vc > 0:
    print('version a > version b')
elif vc == 0:
    print('version a == version b')
elif vc < 0:
    print('version a < version b')
```

ouput:

```
version a > version b
```

Comment: Answer appreciated especially because it doesn't require installing apt_pkg which can be problematic sometimes. python-debian seems to have a fallback mode that implements the version comparison by itself.

Answer (score 3):

As you already mentioned `python-apt` and `python-debian`, but it is 2022 by now and [Python 2.7 is end-of-life](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/), here's the Python 3 code for a Debian based system, where you have installed `python3-debian`:

```
from debian.debian_support import Version
v1 = Version("1:1.3.10-0.3")
v2 = Version("1.3.4-1")
print(v1 > v2)
```

`python3-debian` will automatically used the more efficient version from `python3-apt` if it is installed. But you also can use it explicitly by importing `Version` from `apt`:

```
from apt import Version
```