# Does it matter that my deb version is not Debian native?

Tags: deb

For deploying our server software, we use .deb files, created with the standard Debian packaging scripts.

We're in the process of changing our version numbers. They were `1.$SHA`, e.g. `1.b07be5a5`; now they're a bit more semver, e.g. `2.52.1+e0ce8a81` or `2.53.0-pre+0cdb5e4.dirty`.

This results in a warning:

> Previous package version was Debian native whilst new version is not

What does this mean? Should we care?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should care.

If your packages *are* Debian native (i.e. you build them for Debian and the package's version number is also the version number of each release) then you should stick to a version numbering scheme which preserves this.

If your packages are *not* Debian native, you should number them accordingly.

Debian package version numbers have the general format

```
(epoch:)upstreamversion-packageversion(...fluff)
```

where the dash is significant (and the epoch and trailing stuff are optional); so `1-2` signifies upstream version `1` and the `2` says this is the second Debian package of this upstream version.

Your package versioning scheme where apparently you use a dash for something else is not compatible with this scheme, and needs to be changed one way or another to avoid accidents. Concretely, if the string after `-pre` is a random hash, you could end up in a situation where an older hash is regarded by `dpkg` as newer because `1-pre+012new` is numerically less than `1-pre+987old`.

A concrete suggestion would be to embed a human-readable date and index number before the hash so you have a simple way to avoid this. Then `2.52.1-20191211.01~e0ce8a81` and `2.53.0-20191211.01pre+0cdb5e4.dirty` contain the information you want but still sort correctly if there are packages like `2.52.1-20191211.02~adeadbeef` or `2.53.0-20191211.02pre+000000` published on the same day with hashes which coincidentally sort lower than those of a previous package from the same day.

If your examples are roughly illustrative, the epoch prefix is not mandatory, but adding it would be a good signal to consumers that these version numbers follow a different convention than those in the previous epoch. (When you switch numbering schemes from 11, 12, 13 to 1.0.15 you really have to add an epoch number in front, resulting in 1:1.0.15 instead.) If you don't put an explicit epoch number, the implied epoch number is zero.  So to repeat the previous examples with an epoch number 1 added in front, you'd end up with `1:2.52.1-20191211.01~e0ce8a81` and `1:2.53.0-20191211.01pre+0cdb5e4.dirty`.

The suggested convention keeps the semver package version as "upstream" and the individual package builds as the "Debian version". You can omit the dash or replace it with a different character if you want to remain Debian native (i.e. there is no upstream, and the Debian package version is the authoritative version number).

The details of the Debian version numbering system are documented in the [Debian Policy, Section 5.6.12 `Version`](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#s-f-version)

Comment: This is all good information for the general case. I'm going to ask some clarifying questions about whether _we_ need to care. So: hashes not ordering lexically; we already have that problem. I don't think we need to bump the epoch, since we went from 1.x to 2.x anyway? We're not building _for_ Debian, just using deb as a convenient container.

Comment: Simplifying: can we just swap the `-` for `~` -- relegating everything but the semver to "fluff" -- and move on?

Comment: Yeah, like I said, the epoch doesn't seem strictly necessary here.

Comment: The `~` character (tilde) has some specific semantics as well. I suggest you review the Debian Packaging Policy -- I'll update the answer with a link.

Comment: Maybe play with these [command-line or programmatic comparison methods for Debian version numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957514/how-to-compare-debian-package-versions)